# Linux Bash Script use return of function

Tags: linux, shell, cron

I have a problem with a script.

I wrote a script "getip.sh" that will be called every hour. This script gets the current local IP and calls a wget to transmit this ip address like this

`http://example.com/index.php?localip=192.168.0.1`

If I call the script manually with ./getip.sh everything works just fine.
If this script gets called via crontab:

```
* * * * * cd /home/pi && ./getip.sh >> /home/pi/myLog
```

the Webserver receives only the following 
`http://example.com/index.php?localip=`

Anyone knows the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash

html="http://example.com/index.php?localip=";
netip=`ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`;
netcomp=$html$netip;
wget -O /dev/null -q $netcomp
echo $netcomp
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

cron's path doesn't include /sbin. Use the full path to call ifconfig:

```
netip=`/sbin/ifconfig | grep 'inet addr:'| grep -v '127.0.0.1' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{ print $1}'`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you test like this :

```
    * * * * * /home/pi/getip.sh >> /home/pi/myLog
```